# Looping values inside an array to compare them with another array values

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array

```js
this.selectedItems = [
    { item_id: 1, item_text: 'IN_PROGRESS' },
    { item_id: 2, item_text: 'COMPLETED' },
    { item_id: 3, item_text: 'All' }
];
```

I have an if statement in the example below, where I want to loop through `this.selectedItems` instead of comparing it to an `item` which is not an array (example `const item = {item_id: 1, item_text: "IN_PROGRESS"})`).

```js
item = { item_id: 1, item_text: 'IN_PROGRESS' }

this.newArrayAfterProjectFilter.forEach(element => {
    //  console.log(element)
    if (element.properties.map.aclrq_rfqNum == item.item_text) {
        this.myDataList.push(element);
    }
});
```

how to do this?

Comment: What is `item` in your example?

Comment: Really unclear what do you want to perform.

Comment: @gurisko `item = {item_id: 1, item_text: "IN_PROGRESS"}`

Comment: But you haven't set or declare variable `item` in your code

Comment: @AbrorAbdullaev it is passed parameter, I have written only part of that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.some()` [[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)]

```js
this.selectedItems.some(({item_text}) => item_text === element.properties.map.aclrq_rfqNum);
```